# Laptop Battery compatibility

Tags: laptop, battery, asus-laptop

My Asus K46CB laptop battery is dead. I want to change it, the battery model is "Li-ion Battery Pack A41-K56","15.0 V" , "2950mAh" , "44Wh". But when I search in the internet using the same model (A41-K56) I see different specifications: 14.4 V and 2200mAh. Is this battery compatible with my laptop? why the same model has different specification? This battery should keep charge less than the original one. As far as I know the battery should be able to provide the maximum required current by laptop. So higher mAh for battery is acceptable but in this case 2200mAh is less than the original (2950mAh). Could you please clarify the problem and guide me to decide whether I buy it or not?

Comment: I highly doubt there's a 4.4V version, but the mAh is the capacity, where variation may occur.

Comment: @Jonno Your are right, it was my typo.. 14.4 is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laptop needs a specific (nominal) battery terminal voltage; that's most likely the 15.0 volts. The exact battery terminal voltage will vary over a discharge cycle, but LiIon batteries in general have very good voltage stability over the discharge cycle.

However, LiIon battery *cells* can easily have a voltage slightly above 4 V, and [charging is usually recommended once cell voltage drops to 4.05 V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery#Procedure). LiIon batteries [require very specific safeguards to be safe to use](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/230155/5830) (the question asks about lithium polymer (LiPo) batteries, but the by far highest voted answer specifically points out that for the purposes of that question, the two are "essentially equivalent").

This leads me to believe that the voltage you see quoted might very well be the per-cell voltage, whereas the battery is quoted as the battery terminal voltage. *The two values are not directly comparable.* If you *know* this to be the case, then battery terminal voltage can be approximated as number of cells (in series arrangement) times cell voltage. For example, a four-cell battery with a nominal cell voltage of 4.4 V would have a nominal voltage in the 17.5 V range. High-capacity batteries may connect several such sets in parallel, resulting in the same voltage but larger current capacity.

For the same voltage, capacity (and thus, for a given load, use time) is determined by the number of mAh the battery is rated for. (Note that actually determining this value is a whole can of worms in itself, as the capacity is usually dependent on the discharge rate and ambient temperature. For this reason, battery manufacturers provide data sheets that specify discharge characteristics.) Multiply the two and you get the number of milliwatthours (mWh) the battery can provide; Wh, or in large installations kWh, is a common unit for battery capacity. (Wh = Ah x V, because W = A x V. This applies to DC applications; AC is slightly more complicated.)

All this to say that a difference in mAh or Wh ratings of a battery is generally harmless, **but** the voltage is critical.

## TL;DR, and my advice:

If you are unsure, you should just **contact a reseller or the manufacturer of your laptop and tell them that you want an extra battery for your computer.** They will be able to tell you the model number(s) of the exact manufacturer-issue batteries that fit your particular computer. It will perhaps cost some more, but **you are *vastly* less likely to break anything** or have something burst into flames. For most people, this is a reasonable trade-off.

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote 4.4V by mistake. It was a typo. The actual voltage on the batteries available through the internet is 14.4 V

Comment: @PuyaAmiri Well, 14.4 V and 15.0 V are certainly close enough to be effectively interchangable. That does not alter the final paragraph of my answer, though.